# Can't get virtualenvwrapper to work

Tags: python, powershell, virtualenvwrapper

Successfully ran

```
pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

but I can't get the next two commands to run.

```
PS C:> export WORKON_HOME=~/Envs
```

Error is:

```
The term 'export' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:7
+ export <<<<  WORKON_HOME=~/Envs
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (export:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

```
PS C:> source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Error is:

```
The term 'source' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:7
+ source <<<<  /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (source:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I assume my problem is that I don't know what I'm doing with PowerShell.  Originally, I couldn't get `pip` or `virtualenv` to work at all until I entered:

```psh
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "$env:Path;C:\Python27\Scripts", "User")
```

Once I did that I was able to run `pip` or `virtualenv` from any location without problems.  What I can't figure out is how to successfully run the last two lines specified at the virtualenvwrapper page.

Comment: virtualenvwrapper is for *nix operating systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

virtualenvwrapper is for Unix-like operating systems, e.g. Linux and OS X. Take a look at [virtualenvwrapper-powershell](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper-powershell). It's [officially recommended by virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html#powershell).

There's [virtualenvwrapper-win](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper-win) for the Windows Command Prompt. It's also [recommended by virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html#windows-command-prompt).

There are also [instructions for MSYS](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html#msys).