# I am unable to create a virtualenv in command window to run django projects

Tags: django, python-3.x, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

Could anyone please help me with how to fix the virtuaenv issue on windows 10 - 64-bit pc. I repeatedly keep getting this error while I try to create a virtual env using windows Powershell/Command windows to install Django projects

Error message "mkvirtualenv : The term 'mkvirtualenv' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."

Appreciate your advice

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't get virtualenvwrapper to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31953682/cant-get-virtualenvwrapper-to-work)

Comment: For Python 3, you may want to consider using a `venv` instead of `virtualenv`. `venv` does basically the same thing, but is packaged with Python 3 and doesn't rely on (admittedly elegant) hacks. https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Answer (score 3):

First thing first, create a new folder or directory where you want to create your virtual environment. Once done locate that folder through CMD prompt.

Now, To create virtual environment in command prompt you first need to create a virtual environment wrapper first and with the help of that you can create virtual environment. Make sure you have python in your system before following below steps,  type these commands one by one in your CMD prompt:

```
pip install virtualenvwrapper-win

mkvirtualenv name
```

note: in second code you can choose any name for your virtual environment

note: You will see something like this in your CMD prompt (name) C:\Users....

now install django in this virtual environment, just type the following command

```
pip install django
```

All done !

Extras (optional)

To check django version:

```
django-admin --version
```

(Type this command in your virtual environment only)

To work again on the same virtual environment:

```
workon name
```

( In place of enter the name of your virtual environment)

To stop virtual environment:

```
deactivate
```

( Yup, only this one code)

And then exit, happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

The package which will provide "mkvirtualenv" has not been installed on your computer or your computer cannot locate where it is.
These packages below should be installed:

```
pip install virtualenv
pip install virtualenvwrapper-win
```

Answer (score 0):

i also got the same problem and this how i managed to overcome it

1- specify a directory/folder where you are to store the project using cmd ie for windows
create a folder eg on desktop to store the project

```
C:\Users\zack>cd desktop
```

create a virtual environment folder on desktop using venv in the terminal

```
C:\Users\zack\Desktop>py -m venv django_project
```

activate the virtual environment using scripts\activate.bat

```
     C:\Users\zack\Desktop>django_project\scripts\activate.bat
```

you will see the virtual environment project on the desktop as shown below

```
 (django_project) C:\Users\zack\Desktop>
```

at the end a virtual environment folder is created on the desktop